# Issue with the action element on all Forms (only on our client's server) - Moodle

Tags: php, forms, moodle

All forms have a double URL on the action element and because of this, none of the forms work. All of them lead you to a blank page, the action on every form look like this (example form for adding a new user):

```
action="http://domain.com:8080http://ip:8080/user/editadvanced.php"
```

For some reason all forms as you can notice have domain.com + ip.

The Moodle version is 2.5, and the only difference between theirs and ours is they have apache running on the Port 8080

- The config.php file is good, the path is correct and nothing weird in there.
- The Moodle works on our dev server and on my local server fine, even changing the port, I can't replicate the problem.
- The Moodle code is handle through github so there are not differences between the code on our local environment, dev server and the client's server
- The logs doesn't says anything.
- All forms using Moodle Form API are affected

Any solution or insights would be appreciate it.

Let me know if any further clarification is needed and I'll be happy to edit this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, the Moodle was being run within a VMs with broken configurations. There were configuration issues on the VMs that was causing Moodle to behave strangely.

For any custom form, we can pass the URL through the form call:

```
<?php
// Require your form class.
require_once('custom_form.php');

// Pass the URI where the form will be processed.
$form = new custom_form($CFG->wwwroot . '/blocks/myblockname/file.php');
```

It may help if somebody runs through the same situation.